# Why doesn't the select value in the dropdown change?

Tags: html, jquery

I have two buttons one for adding an employee and one for editing.

Add Record

```
$("#addRow").click(function(){
    departmentName  =   $("#selectPersonnelDepartment option:selected").text();
    locate = $("#selectLocation option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:    "php/insertPersonnel.php",
            type:   "POST",
            dataType:"JSON",
            data: {
                firstName:      $("#addPersonnelFirstName").val(),
                lastName:       $("#addPersonnelLastName").val(),
                emailAddress:   $("#addPersonnelEmailAddress").val(),
                jobTitle:       $("#addPersonnelJobTitle").val(),
                departmentID:   $("#selectPersonnelDepartment").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                var markup = "";
                markup += '<tr>';
                markup += '<td>' + result.data[0].firstName + result.data[0].lastName + result.data[0].jobTitle+ result.data[0].email + '</td>';
                markup += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPersonnelModal" data-id = '+result.data[0].id+'> <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw"> </i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm deletePersonnelBtn" data-bs-toggle ="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePersonnelModal" data-id= '+ result.data[0].id+ '> <i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw"></i> </td>';
                markup += '</tr>';
                $("table tbody").append(markup);
                }
    }); 

    document.getElementById("addPersonnelForm").reset();    

});
```

Edit Record

```
$("#edit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"php/populateLocation.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
            $.each(result.data, function () {
            $("#editPersonnelLocation").append(
            $("<option>", {
              value: this.id,
              text: this.name
            })
        );
    });
}
   

("#editPersonnelLocation").val(locate)//Doesn't change the location
```

I have dynamically populate a drop down in the edit button by getting the locations from a database. When the user selects a location from the add button it should select that location that the user has selected when the user clicks on edit.
This is the dropdown list of locations.

```
<select class = "form-select" id = "editPersonnelLocation">
    <option value="1">London</option>
    <option value="2">Munich</option>
    <option value="3">Tokoyo</option>
    <option value="4">Rome</option>
    <option value="5">Berlin</option>
    <option value="6">Sydney</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: `("#editPersonnelLocation").val(locate)` missing `$` (in the question only, or in your code?) - what's `locate` - how/when does this get set?   In the code provided, this is *outside* the `$.ajax` `success:` so will run before `success:`.  Looks like it's an inferred-global set in the `#add` click `locate = $("#selectLocation option:selected").val();` - in which case, looks like it doesn't change.

Comment: Your brackets aren't balanced in the `Edit Record` code.

Comment: Basically locate gives the index value and Im trying to set the("#editPersonnelLocation").val(locate)to that option but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing `$` for `("#editPersonnelLocation").val(locate)`

Comment: In which case you should vote to close as a typo

Comment: It doesn't work.